# EF Code First link table with 3 foreign keys

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4

In my model I have a User table, Role table, and Organization table.
A User can have more Roles with more Organizations independently.
So far I saw in any tutorial that a link table has two foreign keys (left, right), but in my case I need a link table where there are User-ID, Role-ID, Organization-ID fields as foreign keys and primary keys as well.

some example:

```
user   role       organization
===    ====       ============
u1     admin      orga1
u1     admin      orga12
u1     reviewer   orga3
u2     editor     orga1
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I read that thrice over and still don't get it. Cay you maybe show what you have for structure and what you want out of it? A table with two FK is a many-to-many relationship. Are you looking for a table like that with one more column?

Comment: Then just use two tables? Or is there significance to having a schema like that? I've never come across that type of declaration (not saying it's wrong, just _i've_ never seen it).

Comment: Is there any particular read why you need three FKs in one table (uniqueness constraint maybe?).

Comment: do you mean by two tables that UserRole table and UserOrganization table? this might work i need to think about little bit more.but yes uniqueness is important, however could be managed on Business layer, not in DB ...

Comment: Typically, yes, you'd see `UserRole{UserId,RoleId}` & `UserOrganization{UserId,OrganizationId}`.

Comment: @user2714296 If there is an uniqueness needed it definitely should be done in DB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you actually want is something like a user table, and an OrgRole table.  You then want a joint table User_OrgRole that joins them.  You might want to place a constraint on the table to make sure Org and Role are unique together.

OrgRole might look like this:

- OrgRoleID [KEY]
- Org [FKey]
- Role [FKey]

User_OrgRole might look like this:

- UserID [Key]
- OrgRoleID [Key]

You can certainly do the 3-way join manually, but you will not be able to create any many-to-many style navigational properties or relationships.  You're instead creating what amounts to 3 one to many's.